# Using SpriteKit crashes Xcode 8, is there a way to resolve?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

Whenever I try and add any SpriteKit elements to my project, Xcode crashes. The files are created but not added to the project and if adding them manually, it still crashes when trying to open them. After some searching it looks as though previous versions have suffered with the same issue. I had the same issue with 8 beta 6 too.

Is there anything I can do to help with the issue? I can't find anything on the most up to date version so I'm guessing it's either something I'm doing or a problem with my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same issue when I try to maintain 2 Xcode versions in the same system, it is possible but you should install them into separate directories, for example Xcode_731 and Xcode_8 (my actual version is 8A218a GM, I haven't any crash).

This should be unuseful without crashes, but try also to free some memory (quit also simulator app after your crash), in your terminal:

```
sudo purge
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I already removed the other version and the command did not work.

Comment: So seems simply a bad installation, happen many times. Have you try to remove it and re-install? Or it happened just only if you add particular files?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to do a reinstall, I think, I'll try it now. It's only the SpriteKit files that seem to be affected.

Comment: clear out the cache files,  ~/Library/Caches, and to be safe ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: @FullerPrime This kind of situation happened to me when my code go in segmentation fault 11 (upgrade from Swift 1.x to Swift 2.x), try to check you code, in particular extensions where there are particular reference to memory, unsafepointers or blocks

Comment: All my stuff is currently in swift 3 and this happens with new blank projects too. Completely reinstalled and cleared caches and still no luck.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that I run OSX through Virtual Box. Perhaps it's something deeper causing it.

Comment: @FullerPrime Can you be more specific about it? This crash happen during creation of a new blank project or build or run a new project? it's very different

Comment: Creating and accessing projects is fine. Only when I add any SpriteKit files to the project does it crash. It goes through and crashes when I click Create on the last step.

Comment: @FullerPrime Umh..It seems to be related to the use of GPU drivers in Virtual Box, try to check the video card configuration..

Comment: It looks like you're right. My VBox only has 4mb of graphics memory which won't help and I can't change it despite trying a number of potential solutions so I'm going to try a different environment. Going to mark as the answer as it led me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: You re welcome, you could try to make an hackintosh, its a more complicated system but it can be the solution, search for tonymacosx on the web